# Mysql Query Issue - Insert into select join

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to make an query on my database, I want to move all the rows that have **eventcodes.PRIORITY=1** and **g052013.WCODE=eventcodes.WCODE**, as you can see I copy all the rows from the last month to the new month.
the error I get is :
 `#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` 
and I have the same number of cols in the tables.
 What I am doing wrong here?
Here is my query :

```
insert into g062013
select g052013.pnumber,g052013.id,
g052013.Ccode,
g052013.WCODE,
g052013.ndate,
g052013.TIMECALL,
g052013.EventHandling,
g052013.Endtimecare,
g052013.User,
g052013.TIMEARRIAVAL,
g052013.FREEDATA,
g052013.sendtime from
g052013 RIGHT JOIN eventcodes ON g052013.WCODE=eventcodes.WCODE AND   eventcodes.PRIORITY='1' 
WHERE gyoman052013.EventHandling!=2
```

Comment: Error is telling you that number of columns doesn't match insert fields, can you show your table schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using implicit syntax of `INSERT` statement wherein you did not specify the column names, the number of values must match with the number of columns in the table otherwise wise you'll receive an error message

```
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

To fix this problem, you need to explicitly define the column names on where the values will be saved. Ex,

```
INSERT INTO tableName(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT val1, val2, val3
FROM tableName
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it first and its not working then I remove the "(" ")" after the SELECT and its worked.